# Convert list of lists containing unicode, long and integers to dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, python-unicode

I am working to convert a list of lists containing unicode, long and integers to a dataframe.  A sample of the data is below

```
listOfList = [[u'462', u'40340',u'40340',u'Rochester, MN',u'Rochester, MN Metro Area',u'M1',u'1',u'G3110',6415503905,75224362,u'+43.9496362',u'-092.3360701'], [u'450',u'39580',u'39580',u'Raleigh, NC',u'Raleigh, NC Metro Area',u'M1',u'1',u'G3110',5485217808L,76814164,u'+35.7567464',u'-078.4604412']]
```

Within each child list in the parent listOfList object, elements 8 and 9 will always be long and integer respectively.  However, I can't figure out how to slice the list of lists to exclude elements 8 and 9 within the child lists so that I can encode the unicode as utf-8.  If I can encode the unicode elements, to get a result like the below example cleanlistOfList, loading that to a dataframe is pretty easy.

```
cleanlistOfList = [['462', '40340','40340','Rochester, MN','Rochester, MN Metro Area','M1','1','G3110',6415503905,75224362,'+43.9496362','-092.3360701'],['450','39580','39580','Raleigh, NC','Raleigh, NC Metro Area','M1','1','G3110',5485217808L,76814164,'+35.7567464','-078.4604412']]

df = pd.DataFrame(cleanlistOfList)
```

Does anyone know how to either encode the listOfList to a clean form or load the unclean listOfList to a DataFrame?

Comment: 5485217808L , on the second nested list, produces a syntax error. It might be necessary to remove the L at the end.

Comment: The cleanlistOfList object loads for me into DataFrame df.  I imported in pandas as pd and am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ‘remove’ elements 8 and 9 from all child lists. You can do:

```
NewList = [child[:8] + child[10:] for child in listOfList]
```

This creates a new list without altering the original listOfList.